# Why constructor of Cups class is not being called?

Tags: java

I am getting all the things in this except that why constructor is not being called in this.

```
class Cup {

    Cup(int marker) {
        System.out.println("Cup(" + marker + ")");
    }

    void f(int marker) {
        System.out.println("f(" + marker + ")");
    }
}

class Cups {

    static Cup cup;
    static Cup cup2;

    static {
        cup = new Cup(1);
        cup2 = new Cup(2);
    }

    Cups() {
        System.out.println("Cups()"); // why this is not called
    }
}

public class order3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Inside main()");
        Cups.cup.f(99); // (1)
    }
}
```

Output is :

```
Inside main()
Cup(1)
Cup(2)
f(99)
```

Comment: Because... you're not calling it?

Comment: Because you're not creating an instance but accessing a static member of `Cups`

Comment: You are not creating an instance of Cups class. If you want to create instance you need to call new Cups()

Comment: I got it ,thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you haven't created instance of Cups class. the contructor will only be called if you will create instance using new keywork. like .. Cups cup = new Cups();

Here, you are just using the static object of the Cups class. so inside the static block in the Cups class, you have created the instance of the Cup class that's why the Cup class constructer and methods are getting called.

I hope you understood the concept.

Thanks